# django mail sending very slowly.

Tags: python, django, email, sendmail

i am sending mail using `EmailMessage` in django. this is my code:

```
  message = " test message "
  email = EmailMessage('test subject', message, to=['me@test.com'])
  email.send()
```

but i need to send more emails with different content to different people, so if i do what i did above twice, it is taking very long time to send the mails. like 10 seconds or more. is there any other solution which sends easier and faster?

in php it is very fast. can i also have this in django?

thanks a lot.

Comment: use send_mail() instead

Comment: @catherine, but it is still slow. isnot it because i am in localhost?

Comment: I will search about your problem

Comment: In my case it was ipv6 problem, adding ipv4 address for smtp server in `/etc/hosts` file solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension to the answer of @Thomas Orozco.

django-pigeonpost - allow you to set the time in sending mails, and more ...

https://github.com/dragonfly-science/django-pigeonpost

django cron -  starts at the first request of the webapp and it will send emails each 300 ms (0.3 seconds)

https://sites.google.com/site/vigeblog/blog/sendmailswithdjango

If sending mail is slow again (in your opinion), you have to check your server, refactor your codes, and do testing.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to send more than one email and want to accelerate the process, you can use Django's [`send_mass_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mass-mail) function. The documentation makes it very clear how to use it; here's an example form there:

```
message1 = ('Subject here', 'Here is the message', 'from@example.com', ['first@example.com', 'other@example.com'])
message2 = ('Another Subject', 'Here is another message', 'from@example.com', ['second@test.com'])
send_mass_mail((message1, message2), fail_silently=False)
```

---

This will reuse a single connection for all the emails.

Comment: but it still taking 11 seconds. but i am still in localhost, can this be the reason for slow sending?

Comment: @doniyor You're going to have to do some debugging then. A starting point could be to check the logs on your mail server and those from your application and look for differences.